# object is not a matrix

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem that i cant make a boxplot its saying object is not a matrix i have a problem with 2 ID inputs for columns anyone can help me solve the problem?

Anyone can help me with it i cant see the boxplot and im not sure how it writte corecctly

ui.

```
library(shiny)


    titlePanel("Dáta Quakes"),


            selectInput("selectID", "Vyberte atribút č.1:",choices=c(colnames(quakes))),

            selectInput("selectID2", "Vyberte atribút č.2:",choices=c(colnames(quakes))),
```

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) { 


        output$textik <- renderText({
            vypis=c("Zobrazili ste tabuÄ¾ku s x ", input$selectID, " a y " ,input$selectID2 , "farba ", input$radioID)
            print(vypis)
        })

        output$table <- renderTable(quakes)

        output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
            x    <- quakes[,input$selectID]
            y    <- quakes[,input$selectID2]
            boxplot(x~quakes$y~quakes,  col = input$radioID, border = 'white')
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a few pieces missing with your code, so I filled in some places to make a complete example based on what you have.

`boxplot` will take a formula, such as `y ~ x`. As you already selected the columns of data from `quakes` you only need to include `x` and `y` in your formula. In this case, `y` is a numeric vector which is grouped according to the value of `x`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dáta Quakes"),
  selectInput("selectID", "Vyberte atribút č.1:",choices=c(colnames(quakes))),
  selectInput("selectID2", "Vyberte atribút č.2:",choices=c(colnames(quakes))),
  radioButtons("radioID", label = "Color", choices = c("blue", "green")),
  tableOutput("table"),
  textOutput("textik"),
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$textik <- renderText({
    vypis=c("Zobrazili ste tabuÄ¾ku s x ", input$selectID, " a y " ,input$selectID2 , "farba ", input$radioID)
    print(vypis)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable(head(quakes))

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- quakes[,input$selectID]
    y    <- quakes[,input$selectID2]
    boxplot(y ~ x, col = input$radioID, border = 'white')
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```